# Route [user.profile] not defined. Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to go on profile page but getting error route not defined.I tried to define route but still there 
I defined a new function in User resourceController as profile
and i am defining my route in this way

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@profile');
Route::resource('/user', 'UserController');
```

Here is my Header through which i am going to profile page

```
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{route('user.profile')}}">
                            <i class="icon-user"></i> My Profile </a>
                    </li>
```

Here **User** is name of folder and **profile** is page inside it

Here is method in **UserController**

```
public function profile($request)
    {
        return ('Here');
        return view('user.profile');
    }
```

I was testing but its not coming in profile method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use named route, so you need to [set a name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes) for it:

```
Route::get('user/profile', ['as' => 'user.profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@profile']);
```

Or:

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@profile')->name('user.profile');
```

If you don't want to use named route, you can use `url()` instead of `route()`:

```
<a href="{{ url('user/profile') }}">
```

Comment: One Thing more please how can i pass user id with url or route 
Here 
<a href="{{route('user.profile')}}"> @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @recoverymen, you should use [route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-parameters). But in this case if you want to get an ID of authenticated user, just use `auth()->user()->id` which will always return an ID of currently logged in user.